# Receiving 'TypeError: User is not a constructor' error when exporting Mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

I know this error has already been asked and answered here multiple times, but after sifting through all the previously mentioned fixes I still cannot figure out the error in my code.

> models/index.js

```
require('./users');
```

> models/users.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstname: String,
    ...
});
module.exports =  mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

> routes/signup.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const User = require('../models');
router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
let UserNew = new User({ 
  first_name: req.body.firstName,
  ...
});
```

I am receiving 'TypeError: User is not a constructor' on the line where I try to create a new user.

This is my first MongoDB/Mongoose application and any and all help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: You need to export it from your `models/index.js` as well. `module.exports = require('./users');`

Comment: Thanks Svenskunganka! It worked! You should post this as answer.